# VBA AverageIfs application with OR condition

Tags: excel, if-statement, conditional-statements, average, vba

My data is placed in a range. How do i get an average of a column, with multiple conditions herof an OR condition. in this example `Temprange.columns(2)` should be "High" or "Major"

This should be done without taking an average of two averages as per below example:

```
Dim a As Long
Dim b As Long
Dim ObjectKeyCounter As Long
Dim TempRange As Range
Dim TempArr As Variant
Dim MyArray As Variant

a = Application.WorksheetFunction.AverageIfs(TempRange.Columns(20), _
TempRange.Columns(1), TempArr(ObjectKeyCounter), TempRange.Columns(2), "High")
b = Application.WorksheetFunction.AverageIfs(TempRange.Columns(20), _
TempRange.Columns(1), TempArr(ObjectKeyCounter), TempRange.Columns(2), "Major")
MyArray(1, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(a, b)
```

For some reason i can't find anything on the internet so i guess my way around it (and thereby my search) is wrong.

Edit: Thanks to Scott Holtzman, my solution is as follows:

```
Function AverageIfsOr(ByRef TempArr_Dashboard As Variant, _
 ByRef ObjectKeyCounter As Long, _
 ByRef TempArr_Data As Range, _
 ByRef ColumnToAvg As Long) As Double

    Dim vAvg() As Variant
    Dim vAvgCounter As Integer
    Dim DataRowCounter As Integer

    vAvgCounter = 0
    For DataRowCounter = 1 To TempArr_Data.Rows.Count
        If TempArr_Data(DataRowCounter, 4) = TempArr_Dashboard(ObjectKeyCounter) Then
            If TempArr_Data(DataRowCounter, 11) = "High" Or TempArr_Data(DataRowCounter, 11) = "Major" Then
                vAvgCounter = vAvgCounter + 1
                ReDim Preserve vAvg(vAvgCounter)
                vAvg(vAvgCounter) = TempArr_Data(DataRowCounter, ColumnToAvg)
            End If
        End If
    Next DataRowCounter

    If vAvgCounter = 0 Then
        AverageIfsOr = 0
    Else: AverageIfsOr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(vAvg)
    End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be an easier way but this works.

```
Option Explicit

Sub AverageIfsOr()

Dim v As Variant
Dim vAvg() As Variant

v = Range("C4:E7")

Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To UBound(v) - 1

    If (v(i, 1) = "A" Or v(i, 1) = "B") And (v(i, 2) = "High" Or v(i, 2) = "Major") Then

        ReDim Preserve vAvg(i)
        vAvg(i) = v(i, 3)

    End If

Next

MsgBox Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(vAvg)

End Sub
```

You can play with the If conditions ad nauseam.

Test data is here:

[image]